# Zone transfer Windows Server DNS from NSD

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, nsd, domain-name-system

I have a NSD server being primary server for a zone and want a Windows Server (2008 and 2012 RC) box to be secondary for that zone. Everything is configured and working EXCEPT:

When Windows receives a notify message from NSD it sends an IXFR zone transfer request. However, NSD can't do IXFR requests and answers with "Not implemented".
Unfortunately Windows does *not* retry and request an AXFR transfer now. I have to wait for the refresh timeout to expire to get up-to-date zone data.

Is this a known bug in Windows or is there any configuration option in Windows to change this behaviour?

Comment: By design IXFR is the default transfer initiation command - cannot be changed. Sounds strange that it doesn't retry a full zone transfer though

Answer (score 0):

The [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1995) says only

> Thus, a client should first make an IXFR query using UDP.  If the
> query type is not recognized by the server, an AXFR (preceded by a
> UDP SOA query) **should** be tried, ensuring backward compatibility.

So it's not really a bug of Windows, just annoying